# How to customize the text for django humanize - naturaltime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm using django humanize with the "naturaltime" template filter in my templates
Right now it returns future dates as:
"3 days from now"

I'd like to customize it into something like "in 3 d" (so also changing the order of the words in the output)
How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this task, you cannot customize `humanize`. Instead, I recommend using Django `template tags` and defining a function that transforms the desired date into any format you prefer. To create a **custom template tag**, you can refer to the article below, which provides a simple and easy-to-follow explanation.

**https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/**